# How do I test a nodejs POST web service with file upload using request js and jasmine?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, jasmine

I created a web service with nodeJS (express) that takes a JSON file, reads it and stores its content as a document in a mongodb.

The POST route works fine. The code looks like this

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var fs = require('fs');
router.post('/', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(req.files.swagger.path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    req.body.swagger = JSON.parse(data);
    .
    .
  });
});
```

Basically, it's picking up the data from the JSON file in `req.files` and putting inside `req.body` object.

I need the same thing done on a Jasmine spec file. I'm able to physically test the web service using POSTman but I need to test it through a spec file using jasmine. For now, I'd like to check if the web-service throws a `200 OK` status, but it's throwing a `500`

So far, my `jasmine-node` test suite looks like this

```
describe("POST /", function() {

it("returns status code 200", function(done) {
  var req = request.post(base_url, function(error, response, body) {
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });

  var form = req.form();
  form.append('file','<FILE_DATA>', {
    filename : "sample.json",
    contentType : "text/plain"
  });
  console.log("Form", form);

  });
});
```

How do I upload files onto nodejs server programatically, so that I can pick up the file from `req.files` in my spec?

Comment: Are you actually calling your field 'file' instead of 'swagger' like your server script is expecting?